# Using join in Laravel, toArray method does not work

Tags: json, laravel, left-join

The code works fine like this. no problem with toArray

```
   $restaurants = Restorant::where(['active'=>1])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
    $data = [];
    $item = [];

    foreach ($restaurants as $rest_key => $rest_value) {
        $item = $rest_value->toArray();
        $item["ratings"] = [];
        $item["time_to_prepare_order_in_minutes"] = [];

        $ratings = DB::table('ratings')->where('rateable_id', '=', $rest_value->id)->get();
        foreach ($ratings as $rating_key => $ratings_value) {
            $item["ratings"][] = [
                "sub_id" => $ratings_value->id,
                "rating" => $ratings_value->rating,
            ];
        }

        $configs = DB::table('configs')->where('key','=','time_to_prepare_order_in_minutes')->where('model_id','=',$rest_value->id)->first();
        $item["time_to_prepare_order_in_minutes"] = $configs->value;


        $data[] = $item;
    }

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $data,
        'status' => true
    ]);
```

But I don't know how to do this when I use join. I also did this logic. How can I do this better? My aim is to tire the server as little as possible while retrieving data in json format. I tried to do it with DB->with option but it gave different errors.

```
$restaurants = DB::table('companies')->select('companies.*', 'configs.key', 'configs.value')->leftJoin('configs', 'configs.model_id', '=', 'companies.id')->where('configs.key', '=', 'time_to_prepare_order_in_minutes')->where('companies.active', '=', 1)->orderBy('companies.id', 'desc')->limit(10)->get();
    $columns = Schema::getColumnListing('companies');

    $data = [];
    $item = [];
    foreach ($restaurants as $rest_key => $rest_value) {
        foreach ($columns as $col_key => $col_value) {
            $cKey = $columns[$col_key];
            $item[$cKey] = $rest_value->$cKey;
        }

        $item["ratings"] = [];

        $ratings = DB::table('ratings')->where('rateable_id', '=', $rest_value->id)->get();
        foreach ($ratings as $rating_key => $ratings_value) {
            $item["ratings"][] = [
                "sub_id" => $ratings_value->id,
                "rating" => $ratings_value->rating,
            ];
        }

        $data[] = $item;
    }


    return response()->json([
        'data' => $data,
        'status' => true
    ]);
```

Comment: You have to use relations for tables and it is better to use eloquent for this. Check out: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships. If you want to do with query builder, then check `join` method: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#joins

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem. The -> sign solved my problem.

```
$data = [];
    $item = [];
    foreach ($cityRestaurants as $city_key => $city_value) {
        $item = $city_value;
        $item->ratings = [];

        $ratings = DB::table('ratings')->where('rateable_id', '=', $city_value->id)->get();
        foreach ($ratings as $rating_key => $ratings_value) {
            $item->ratings[] = [
                "sub_id" => $ratings_value->id,
                "rating" => $ratings_value->rating,
            ];
        }

        $configs = DB::table('configs')->where('key','=','time_to_prepare_order_in_minutes')->where('model_id','=',$city_value->id)->first();
        $item->time_to_prepare_order_in_minutes = $configs->value;

        $data[] = $item;
    }
```